# Why do I get an undefined value if the value is defined? using eval()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, eval

I cant quite figure out why I am getting an `undefined` in my console...

Each object being iterated over has the property defined.

Where did I go wrong??

the collection looks like this:

```
var a = [
    {
        city: 'Tucson',
        state: 'AR',
        zipcode: 85701
    },
    {
        city: 'Orlando',
        state: 'FL',
        zipcode: 32828
    },
    {
        city: 'Apopka',
        state: 'FL',
        zipcode: "32703",
    },
    {
        city: 'Compton',
        state: 'CA',
        zipcode: 90220
    }
];
```

here's the function:

```
function reduce(collection, condition){

    var map = [];

    for (let v in collection){
        var cl = [], r, e, matches, m;
        if ('string' === typeof condition) {

            r = new RegExp(/([\w]+)\s*?(?=(>|<|>=|<=|==|===|!=|!==))/g);

            matches = condition.match( r );

            var nm = condition;

            matches.forEach(function(m, index){
                // outputs state console.log(m);
                nm = nm.replace(m, (collection[v][String(m)]) + ' ' );
                console.dir(collection[v]);
                console.dir(m + " replaced by " + collection[v][m] +  ", gets you: " + nm);

            });
            cl.push(m);

            //if (eval(condition) === true) {   map.push(collection[v]); }

        } else if ('object' === typeof condition){
            for (let c in condition){

                r = new RegExp("(" + collection[v][c] + ")*(>|<|>=|<=|==|===|!=|!==)", "g");

                e = condition[c];

                matches = condition[c].match( r );

                if (0 < matches.length) {
                    matches.forEach(function(m, index){

                        if ( condition[c].indexOf(c) === -1 ) {
                            e = e.replace(m, ( (typeof collection[v][c] === 'string') ? "'" + collection[v][c] + "'" : collection[v][c] ) + " " + m);
                        }
                    });
                };
                cl.push(e);
            }


            if (eval(cl.join(" && ")) === true) {   map.push(collection[v]); }
        };

        console.log(cl.join(" && "));

    }
    return map;
}
```

...

and here's the call to:

`var floridians = reduce(a, "state == 'FL'");`

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I think you should specifically say what's appearing to be undefined.

Comment: Just a question, is their a true reason that you *overcomplicate* the thing? You are basically rewritting Array.prototype.filter()

Comment: .... and redefining the meaning of `reduce` for which there is `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Comment: In my console I had to add `'use strict';` in the reduce function to allow it to work in the latest chrome due to: "Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode", but I did not get an undefined error

Comment: ...and using `for-in` on an array without safeguards?

Comment: @Cohars: not really, because `filter` doesn't support computed expressions like `state='FL'`

Comment: no it supports the much safer `function(e){ return e.state == 'FL'; }`

Comment: You could use it like that: `a.filter(a => a.state == 'FL')`, or without the arrow  function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `undefined` is because your variable `m` (which you think contains the string "state") has a trailing space. When used in the square-bracket notation to read the property of your object, this returns `undefined`.

This was found using good ol' fashioned debugging: https://jsfiddle.net/wLs3o9mk/ - Your use of `console.dir` was masking the issue, it appears to collapse multiple spaces (like HTML). It became pretty obvious when changing to `console.log` which does not.